# calling an ID EJSUploader on Blazor like as javascript

Tags: razor, syncfusion, blazor

I try create project using Blazor (server-side) and I want to add JavaScript on .razor pages.

I am really confused about calling an ID on Blazor like javascript uses syncfusion component EJSUploader. Can it be done? I've tried some solutions, but it doesn't run as I expected.

Comment: read this : https://chrissainty.com/using-javascript-interop-in-razor-components-and-blazor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings from Syncfusion support.

We would like to inform you that, there is no need to generate JavaScript pages for calling the Syncfusion Uploader component. Because, we have provided the Uploader component in Blazor platform. In the Razor pages, we can accomplish all the JavaScript features for Uploader component.

Please refer the below UG and Demo link to know more about Blazor Uploader component.

**UG Link:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-blazor/documentation/uploader/getting-started/?no-cache=1

**Demo Link:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-blazor/Uploader/DefaultFunctionalities

If you are facing any issues with our Blazor component, please let us know. We’re happy to assist you.

Regards,

Sureshkumar P.